# why is probability not considered part of pure mathematics?

Tags: probability

wikipedia considers probability a part of applied mathematics, and it doesn't seem to fall under one of the four areas of mathematics (algebra, number theory, topology/geometry,analysis).

Nevertheless it seems to me to be a very fundamental mathematical concept, so why is it not considered a part of pure mathematics?

Comment: Some people say that, because probability can be viewed as the study of functions (or measures) with very particular properties (non-negative, integrate to $1$, and so on), the field should be viewed as an applied branch of real analysis.  Others would argue that the general theory of probability, and the wide variety of implications it has, should be viewed as a separate topic within math.  In the end, I'd say that was more of a semantic distinction than a substantive one.

Comment: Probability is built on measure theory, which is part of analysis.

Comment: Do not take wikipedia's classification to represent the consensus opinion.

Comment: combinatorics are a part of mathematics, but probability is just a use of it, you know that many fields use mathematics in concrete aims, so anything which just take exploitation of maths without promoting it isnt maths itself, i hope that is close to be an acceptable reason.

Comment: @Agawa011 Combinatorial methods are mostly relevant in the study of discrete probability distributions...which is one of the more elementary topics in probability theory. So your post doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is fundamentally flawed. Firstly, there is no clear distinction between pure and applied mathematics --- for example, is the study of PDEs like the Navier--Stokes equation pure or applied mathematics? One proves theorems and uses general theory just like in pure mathematics, but PDEs obviously have applications in physics. The classification is very imprecise.

Secondly, you say it doesn't fall under the "four areas of mathematics", algebra, number theory, topology/geometry, analysis. I have no idea where you got this "classification" from, but it's definitely far from comprehensive. For example, where is set theory? Dynamical systems? Combinatorics? Graph theory? Are you really suggesting these are not considered mathematics?

Probability **is** a part of pure mathematics, though of course it also has extremely significant applications in applied math, or even outside of mathematics (e.g. in economics, finance, etc). Both can be true at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that probability and randomness are concepts of pure mathematical reasoning as fundamental as those of space, number and structure. In fact, it can be considered as a generalization of what is commonly referred to "pure math", like those four "branches" you mention.

Such "pure math" can be described as an object the part of probability theory concerned with events ocurring with probability 1 or 0. These events are then called theorems, things which *always* or *never* happen. Theorems with some additional hypothesis are events with *conditional* probability equal to 0 or 1, i. e., things that always or never happen, provided that some other thing has already happened (meaning, provided the hypotheses are true).

In truth, those kinds of divisions are artificial and useless. There's no real meaning to "pure" math. Branches are used by academics as a way to organize knowledge and an excuse to specialize and never learn anything outside "their" field. The only thing that actually exists are mathematical ideas, and all of them embrace each other. There's no meaningful separation between them as objects of the mind.

Comment: I wouldn't say the word "pure" is an excuse to specialize. One can be very specialized in an applied situation as well.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I was referring to the whole idea of "branches" and differentiated "parts". That is the excuse to specialize. First they divide "thinking" into "number theory thinking", "applied mathematics thinking" and so on, and then they create differentiated disciplines, schools, fields in which people specialize.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret the applied and pure dichotomy in math is:

Applied math is taking established mathematical results and utilizing them in describing, understanding and solving real-world problems.

Pure math is a collection of mathematical results that serve the purpose describing, understanding and solving abstract problems. That is, problems which aren't a real-world problems.

They are not absolutely disjoint but rather are important parts of the whole of mathematics. Moreover, despite my above "definitions", I would say there is no strongly distinct line between the two. A research paper could have both pure math results and applied math results within it.

Probability falls under measure theory which is part of analysis, but also has the ability to be applied to real-world problems. I would say it is both.

Comment: Check out Mark Kac, Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis, and Number Theory (Carus Monograph 12) for examples of how it is used in pure math!